# Sharepoint webservice call not returning list

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

I'm sending the following:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
<soap:Body>
     <GetList xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">
         <listName>{5DB680A5-EFCB-4F48-AC80-835AFBCE9FDA}</listName>
     </GetList>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

but am getting back results for GetListCollection

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetListCollectionResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"><GetListCollectionResult>...
```

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I tried this same code (substituting a GUID from my sharepoint site) and managed to get back a GetListResult object.  What tool are you using to retrieve the data. Are you sure what you're getting back is the result of the above request?

Comment: Hi Robbert - I got it working, I was making an error in my NSMutableRequet set up.